# Using the xcolor package

Tags: packages

When I use the command `\usepackage{xcolor}` I get an error saying `xcolor.sty` was not found. Even though other commands like `\usepackage{amsmath}` have worked. I am very new to LaTeX and am not sure why this is happening, and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! have a look at [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) :)

Comment: I don't think it applies to me since I have Miktex not Tex Live?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the useful tips, I was finally able to install the package, and I realized my main problem was that I was not being allowed to install the packages due to some random security permissions problem (even though this is my own personal laptop), so I have to manually install a package everythime I need one:(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is an update issue. I think that the package is simply not installed.

MiKTeX has the option to install missing packages on-the-fly. You can check if this option is enabled by looking by opening the "Settings" application of your MiKTeX installation.

This application can be found by going to:"Start Menu --> MiKTeX 2.x --> Maintenance --> Settings". At the bottom of the first tab, the "General" tab, there should be the option to enable the "on-the-fly installation process". This should solve any issues with missing packages when you compile your documents.

In the same "Maintenance" folder you will also find the applications to update ("Update") and manually manage the packages to be isntalled/removed/updated ("Package Manager"). More information on those two can be found on the [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) provided by cmhughes.

I hope this has cleared some of the maintenance work needed to install/update/remove packages.